# Laravel React - Translating Email Markdown Files

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am currently upgrading my app from Blade to React/Inertia.
I used to access my translations in my markdown files as below;

```
@component('mail::message')
<h2>@lang('Emails.emailtitle')</h2>
@endcomponent
```

This no longer works.

I use react-i18next to load my translation with React/Inertia set-up. Below is the set-up I have in my JSX files.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { t } = useTranslation();

{t("frontend:text1")}
```

How could I load my translations in my markdowns? Can anyone help?

Thank you.